# column with specified length value

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I want to create a column with SQL Server which would accept values with exact 6 digits. Values with more or less number of digits would be not accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple `CHECK` constraint and check column length. This was already told, but solution wasn't posted, so here I am:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    YourSixDigitColumn INT
    , CONSTRAINT CK_CheckLength CHECK (LEN(YourSixDigitColumn) = 6)
);
```

If I'd try to insert one of these:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
VALUES (12345);

INSERT INTO dbo.Test
VALUES (1234567);
```

It would throw me this nasty error message:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 7 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the CHECK constraint "CK_CheckLength". The conflict occurred in
>   database "master", table "dbo.Test", column 'YourSixDigitColumn'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

And this SQL Statement works flawlessly:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test
VALUES (123456);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use either `char(6)` or `Decimal(6,0)`.

But to enforce that it can't be less than 6 digits, you'll need to use a `check constraint`.

Comment: I tried to use this `ADD CONSTRAINT [MinLengthConstraint] CHECK (DATALENGTH([your_column]) = 11)` but it didn't work

Comment: Why did you use 11?   The Datalength of a 6-character string is 6.

Comment: Tab Alleman - You cannot use DATALENGTH for this.  It returns the number of bytes required to store a value.  Example:  the integers 1 and 999999 both have a DATALENGTH of 4.  You could use LEN, but really this is for strings and not numbers.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(DATALENGTH_TSQL);k(SQL13.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL13.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true

Comment: @destination-data you are correct if the OP is using a numeric data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server's [Check Constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms190377.aspx) for this. These are a great way of limiting the allowed values within a column.

If your six digits are always a whole number your rule would look this:

```
ColumnA >= 100000 AND ColumnA <= 999999.
```